# Multiple Regression with Second Factor that Increases Volatility

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, variance, standard-deviation, nonlinear-regression

I'm trying to estimate y, how likely a quantity is to increase/decrease by x<sub>1</sub>% using historical data. This part is pretty straightforward. I check history for how many times that quantity has increased by x<sub>1</sub>% or more historically, then take the number of times it increases by x<sub>1</sub>% or more and divide by the total of times in the dataset.

The outcome looks like this:

[image]

That's pretty good, but come to find out there is another factor, x<sub>2</sub>, that is highly correlated with this outcome and can be incorporated for a more accurate prediction.

[image]

This is the same graph but with x<sub>2</sub> added on the y axis. The x axis is x<sub>1</sub> (%increase/decrease) and the y axis is the new factor x<sub>2</sub>. As you can see the higher x<sub>2</sub> is the higher the liklihood for a large increase/decrease to occur

It's obviously true that as x<sub>2</sub> increases, the odds of an increase of x<sub>1</sub>% go up, and vice versa. Which should mean that the original graph should become more extreme with higher x<sub>2</sub> and less extreme with lower x<sub>2</sub>. The issue is to what degree exactly?

Knowing a bit about statistics, (but not as much as you guys) I would usually attempt to use a multiple regression method here. But this time, because x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub> aren't related in a theoretically 1:1 way, but rather as a range of probability, I don't know what to do.

Also, while I'm used to running multiple regressions on linear data, it's not clear that x<sub>2</sub> is going to have a linear relationship. While it's obvious that the final equation is going to look something like the equation for graph 1 with an added factor for x<sub>2</sub>, it's not clear to me if it would be Linear, logarithmic, or exponential.

There are some obviously clugey ways I could go about this. For instance, I could segment the data into x<sub>2</sub> = 10-14, x<sub>2</sub>= 14-18, etc. and get a standard deviation estimate for each slice. The issue with this is that the slices are going to either have too few points to have a representative sample, or too large as to lack precision. This would be a really, really unideal option.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for the type of method I should be trying here? I'm happy to learn, but I don't know what to look into.